# How to pass mapped array data to the Modal in react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I don't know what I'm doing wrong i Have a array of `subquestions` nested inside the `questions` I want to show the `subquestions` data into the modal on click event . I'm able to show the modal but data dosnt gets into the model and no error was displayed.

**Can anybody find I'm doing wrong here ? and how to fix this issue ?**

**Relevent Code**

```
{questions
    ? questions.map((question) => (
        <div className="py-2 my-2" key={question.id}>
          {question.question_brand === order.prod_brand ? (
            <Fragment>
              <Modal
                show={show}
                onHide={onDiscard}
                toggle={() => setShow(!show)}
                size="lg"
                aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
                centered
              >
                <Modal.Header closeButton>
                  <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">Also Answer</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                  <h4>Sub Questions</h4>
                  // THIS IS A PROBLEMATIC AREA 
                  {questions.subquestions
                    ? questions.subquestions.map((sub) => (
                        <Card classNames="mx-2 py-2" key={sub.id}>
                          <Card.Header>{sub.sub_question}</Card.Header>
                        </Card>
                      ))
                    : null}
                </Modal.Body>
                <Modal.Footer>
                  <Button variant="dark" onClick={onDiscard}>
                    Close
                  </Button>
                </Modal.Footer>
              </Modal>
            </Fragment>
          ) : null}
        </div>
      ))
    : null}
```

This is how the data looks:
[

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "question_brand": "Apple (Laptop)",
    "question": "Does Your Macbook Gets On Properly",
    "user_choice": null,
    "subquestions": []
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "question_brand": "Apple (Laptop)",
    "question": "Does Your Laptop's Screen wrorks ?",
    "user_choice": null,
    "subquestions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "sub_question": "Does this has malfunctioned Screen ?",
            "user_choice": null,
            "image": null,
            "weightage": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "sub_question": "Does this have Brightness Problems",
            "user_choice": null,
            "image": null,
            "weightage": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: Where is the questions data coming from

Comment: Question data is coming from redux hook

Comment: So the data maybe falsy therefore you render null, try to console the data check if it is undefined or some data is present

Comment: Could you paste it as a codebox link

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-tree-2nq0g3?file=/src/fullCode.js I have pasted a full component here , you can view it , there are `specialQuestions` with their sub question , In this question I retracted a lot of code for minimalist code example but in this link you can watch it all, it wont run but you can see it.

Comment: are you able to display data for the question object with id=3?  If you want to display modal body based on the subquestions array use "questions.subquestions.length" .  questions.subquestions will evaluate to true even for empty array.

Comment: Yes i m able to show these objects but want sub questions inside the modal